# C# DevExpress What is the way to make each cell of a column having its own display format?

Tags: c#, devexpress-wpf

Code Column

```
 var col = new GridColumn {
            Header = "value",
            Binding = new Binding {
                Path = new PropertyPath(
                    $"{nameof(DivisionRegionTimingVM.Months)}[{monthIndex}]." +
                    $"{nameof(DivisionTimingMonthVM.Week)}[{weekIndex}]." +
                    $"{nameof(DivisionTimingWeekVM.Value)}"
                ),
                Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
            }
        };

        col.SetBinding(
            ColumnBase.EditSettingsProperty,
            new Binding {
                Source = _division,
                Path = new PropertyPath(
                    $"{nameof(DivisionRegionTimingVM.Months)}[{monthIndex}]." +
                    $"{nameof(DivisionTimingMonthVM.Week)}[{weekIndex}]." +
                    $"{nameof(DivisionTimingWeekVM.EditSettings)}"
                )
            }
        );
```

Binding takes the first element as a basis!
Was looking for the key in the internet but didn’t find the solution

tabe

---

```
|        |         |_____month__________|__________month_____|
|  Name  |   Name  |_day_|_day_|_day____|_day_|_day_|_day____|
|        |Variation| val | val | val    | val | val | val    |
|________|_________|_____|_____|________|_____|_____|________|
|        |_Growth__|_170_|_170_|___170__|_170_|_170_|__170___|
|        |____Wt___|__72_|__75_|___73___|__71_|__68_|__70____|
|David   |___20____|_20%_|_20%_|___20%__|_20%_|_20%_|__20%___|
|________|___10____|_80%_|_80%_|___80%__|_80%_|_80%_|__80%___|
```

Comment: Side question? Is there a problem with the devexpress support? You have paid for that and they have dedicated support people to help you with that. Why not ask the pros on the topic?

Comment: @Ralf No issues with support, usually find the necessary data on this platform. Thank you for the reply, will contact them.